# wpf: validate text box after button clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I am new to WPF(4.0) and I am trying to make a simple form with some TEXTBOX and a SUBMIT BUTTON.

when user click on the submit Button and the program checks if all Textboxs filled, if not, the unfilled Textbox will surrounded by a "Red Border".

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border Padding>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox  Name="name_textbox"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>


    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">Submit</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>        
</StackPanel>
```

I read and I am trying to understand the following as well as some other documents and stack overflow posts and I found there are lots of things and terms that i could not understand.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation#welcome

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property

My QUESTION is: 
I think there are something to do with data binding validation, and apart from that what else should I need to know?

or are there any good resources recommend or quick examples?

I am lost and hope someone could help, thanks!

Comment: if you are using `ICommand` you can validate your button using canexecute method. i recommend reading mvvm that will give you more insight.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of a class that i write to check validation after an element losts focus.

add FocusAdvancement in your window and set ValidationOnLostFocus to true. and add your custom validation in textbox ValidationRules.

```
public static class FocusAdvancement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationOnLostFocusProperty=
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ("ValidationOnLostFocus",typeof (bool),typeof (FocusAdvancement),new UIPropertyMetadata (OnValidationOnLostFocusPropertyChanged));

    public static bool GetValidationOnLostFocusProperty(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue (ValidationOnLostFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetValidationOnLostFocusProperty(DependencyObject d,bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue (ValidationOnLostFocusProperty,value);
    }

    private static void OnValidationOnLostFocusPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element=(UIElement)d;
        if (element==null)
            return;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            element.LostFocus+=LostFocus;
        }
        else
            element.GotFocus-=LostFocus;
    }

    private static void LostFocus(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element=(UIElement)sender;

        if (element!=null)
        {
            TextBox oTextBox=(TextBox)element;
            oTextBox.GetBindingExpression (TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource ();
        }
    }
```